# Saving a Excel file with current date in python3

Tags: python, excel, timestamp

I would like to save the excel file(File Name- Stock) in python along with current date, let me know how to save it with date.
Below is the Script am using normally to save the excel files.

```
 path=r"\C:\User\ASL - Stock Reports\Stock.xlsx"
 writer=pd.ExcelWriter(path,engine='xlsxwriter')
 Overall_Stock.to_excel(writer, index=False)
 writer.save()
 writer.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

curr_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y_%m_%d')

Overall_Stock.to_excel(path.split('.xlsx')[0] + '_' + curr_date + '.xlsx',  index=False)
```

Comment: @ Mayank Porwal, am getting the below Error.                                         
 Error: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: do `import datetime`.

Comment: have you done this: `from datetime import datetime` ??

Comment: yeah, now am getting this error.                                                                           
 TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'writer'

Comment: Updated my answer. Simply remove `writer=`.

Comment: thanks, but now am getting fresh error:ValueError:                                                           No engine for filetype: 'xlsx_2020_04_17'

Comment: @ Mayank : Thanks i got the output based on the below Script                          
  import time
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
excelfilename = "File Name"+TodaysDate +".xlsx"                  
  Source.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = '{}-{}-{}'.format(now.year, now.month, now.day)
filename = 'Name_of_your_file' + '_' + date


path=r"\C:\User\ASL - Stock Reports\Stock.xlsx"
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(path, sheet_name = filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
Overall_Stock.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

This should work. Let me know if it does not.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for. Your solution will save the excel file with sheet named with `date`. He wants to append date in the filename itself.

Comment: You're right. I edited the code to make it work they way OP intended. Thank you!

Comment: hi Walker am getting the below Error while the file is starts to write from 
  Python.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Stock'

Comment: I assume it happens because there is a space in your path "\C:\User\ASL - Stock Reports\Stock.xlsx". Change your path name to "\C:\User\ASL_Stock_Reports\Stock.xlsx". I think that should solve the issue. Let me know if it doesn't.